# File /src/environments/environment.ts does not exist angular 15

Tags: angular, angularfire

I am trying to build **angular 15** with angularfire **@angular/fire@7.5.0**. But i encountered this error

```
✔ Downloading configuration data of your Firebase WEB app

File /src/environments/environment.ts does not exist
```

I noticed some config files were missing too, although i created a brand new project

Comment: Seems like an [open bug](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3290)

Comment: If environments files are missing then you can add them using https://angular.io/cli/generate#environments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [open ticket](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3294) which points to the support of [angular 15](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3290) : In short `/src/environments/environment.ts` is optional now with Angular 15 but `angular-fire` doesn't handle that.

You can workaround this error by [creating an environement file](https://angular.io/cli/generate#environments).

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a little late but in someone comes to this section with the same problem and it's having troubles with `ng g environments`, you can follow [this](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-environment-specific-defaults) guide. It worked for me by just creating a default environment.